# Merge two arrays in PHP

Tags: php

I have two arrays:

```
$a = array([0]=>1 [1]=>2 [2]=>3);
$b = array([0]=>a [1]=>b [2]=>c);
```

I want to merge them like

```
$ab=array( [a]=>array([0]=>1 [1]=>2 [2]=>3) 
           [b]=>array([0]=>a [1]=>b [2]=>c)  );
```

How to do this ?

I tried `array_merge()` but it does not work as I want it to.

Comment: Does not look like you want to merge them. Just do `$ab = array('a' => $a, ...)`... straightforward?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case you can just go:

```
$ab = array('a' => $a, 'b' => $b);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `compact()` method:

```
$ab = compact('a', 'b');
```

where `'a'` and `'b'` will used as array keys and treated as variable names to assign values, so it will do `array('a' => $a, 'b' => $b)`

Answer (score 1):

You've pretty much written the answer already.

```
$ab = array('a' => $a, 'b' => $b);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ab = array('a' => $a, 'b' => $b);
```

Will result in:

```
$ab['a'] = array([0] => 1, [1] => 2, [2] => 3);
$ab['b'] = array([0] => a, [1] => b, [2] => c);
```

Or you can just do `$ab = array($a, $b)` if you don't want the keys (it is unclear in your question if a and b are strings or integers).